# Series convergence $(-1)^n n\tan\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I tried to prove the convergence of this series with the ratio and root test but neither worked. I also couldn't find another series to compare.
I understand that $\tan\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing  and the partial sums too.

I have no idea what to try now

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n n\tan\frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: Hint: near $0$, $\tan(x)$ is very much like $x$ (look at the Taylor series), so your sum is essentially $\sum (-1)^n\cdot 1$, which does _not_ converge...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$n\tan\left(\dfrac1n\right)=\frac1{\cos\left(\dfrac1n\right)}\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac1n\right)}{\dfrac 1n}$$ shows that the general term does not tend to zero.

Comment: When I take the $\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}$ the right side became $\left( \frac{1}{1}\right) \frac{0}{0}$, because $\frac{0}{0}$ I apply L'Hôpital then it goes to 1.
Is it right?

Comment: @CarlosEduardo Are you familiar with the classical limit $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\sin x}}{x} = 1?
$$

Comment: @CarlosEduardo that is one way of doing it, yes. For another way (using Maclaurin series of $\sin(x)$), see my answer.

Comment: @Gary yes. I didn't notice I could use the it.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Yves Daoust's terse answer,

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\dfrac1n\right) = 1\neq 0,\ $ so $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{\cos\left(\dfrac1n\right)}\right) = \frac{1}{1} = 1,\ $ and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions), we see that:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac1n\right)}{\dfrac 1n}\right) = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\left(\dfrac1n\right)-\frac{\left(\dfrac1n\right)^3}{3} + \frac{\left(\dfrac1n\right)^5}{5}+\ldots}{\dfrac 1n}\right) = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\left(\dfrac1n\right)^2}{3} + \frac{\left(\dfrac1n\right)^4}{5}+\ldots\right) = 1.$$

Therefore,

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\tan\left(\dfrac1n\right)\right)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{\cos\left(\dfrac1n\right)}\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac1n\right)}{\dfrac 1n}\right) = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{\cos\left(\dfrac1n\right)}\right)\ \cdot\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac1n\right)}{\dfrac 1n}\right) = 1\cdot 1 = 1.$$